# how i can get started with MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs, express

i'm trying to get started with Mean stack and i visited the website http://www.mean.io/, and in the section "quick install" displays some command,
where i have to put these commands?
There is a tutorial to get started with mean stack step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to install [node.js](http://nodejs.org) to your machine.

Then use [npm](http://npmjs.org) to install the dependencies. You can find many tutorials on how to get started with MEAN stack.

[Check this](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/)

Comment: i installed node.js, mongoDB and git but while trying to execute the command 'npm Install' i get the following error: fatal error: Git is not installed or not in the path..i have searched about this error but i have not found anything

Comment: Which OS you are using?